# Lightning tab not loading and throws access check error for ltng:require ?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Since a couple patches ago, My lightning component has not been working correctly in a lightning tab.

When I first open the browser, and I navigate to the tab containing my component for the first time, everything works perfectly, no issues at all. However, when I move to a different tab and navigate back to the lightning tab, or I refresh the page, the app no longer works, and instead throws an error every time I attempt to open the tab.

The error is

```
    [NoErrorObjectAvailable] Access Check Failed! 
AuraComponentService.createComponentFromConfig(): 'markup://ltng:require' is not visible to
 'markup://mylongnamespace:AppContainer {8:1;0}'.
```

This is obviously invalid since every lightning component should be able to access the ltng:require markup, not to mention that it works on the first try, so something is screwed up on the subsequent loads only.

If I disable the "Enforce Lightning Components Access Checks" security updates, I no longer get the error popup, but the app still does not load.

The console now displays an exception,

```
TypeError: Action failed: ltng$require$controller$init [TypeError: valueProvider.get is not a function]
```

and the offending line is from the Aura Framework itself.. [image: Aura error]

Neither error makes any sense to me and I am pretty lost on what I am supposed to do. If anyone could help me out or provide an explanation, it would be appreciated.

Comment: having same issue, did you find any work around without disabling security updates?

Comment: @realnumber : most likely this https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000183G6QAI